# Core Data Concurrency and thread safe solution

Tags: ios, multithreading, core-data, singleton

I'm looking at this tutorial: [A Guide to Core Data Concurrency](http://robots.thoughtbot.com/core-data)

In particular I'm looking at the solution number 1 where it is used a singleton and two contexts.

My question is: are the methods to retrieve the contexts (and other methods) thread safe? How come there is no control?

Answer (score 0):

Referencing the contexts is threadsafe but you have to do any operations on the context's private queue if it is of type NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType. The second solution, although a bit overly complex with all the singletons and getters, fits a pattern i've been using and has seemed to be common for a while:

http://www.cocoanetics.com/2012/07/multi-context-coredata/

From what I've seen, save notifications are being replaced by automatic propagation through parent contexts.

XCode 6 and Yosemite also seem to have an improvement in core data debugging: http://oleb.net/blog/2014/06/core-data-concurrency-debugging/. You should be able to catch common thread violations if you set  -com.apple.CoreData.ConcurrencyDebug 1 for the debug scheme.